NgbDatePicker- Previous date is getting selected in pacific time zone
In my angular project, I am using NgbDatePicker to show date control. The problem is occuring when i'm changing the time zone to Pacific time(US Canada). When i'm selecting the date 17/07/2024 it is being displayed as 16/07/2024 as in the screenshot.
Where as when the timezone is indian, the date is correctly displaying
enter image description here
html code
<div *ngIf="element.type === 'text' && element.inputType === 'date'">
                <input
                  id="{{ element.name }}"
                  class="form-control"
                  #minDateReportedInput
                  #minDateReportedDatepicker="ngbDatepicker"
                  name="minDateReported"
                  ngbDatepicker
                  readonly
                  (click)="minDateReportedDatepicker.toggle()"
                  (keyup.space)="minDateReportedDatepicker.toggle()"
                  (dateSelect)="onMinDateReported($event, element)"
                />
                <div *ngIf="minDateReportedInput.value" class="input-group-append">
                  <button
                    class="btn btn-link px-2"
                    type="button"
                    [title]="'AbpUi::Clear' | abpLocalization"
                    (click)="
                      minDateReportedDatepicker.writeValue(null);
                      minDateReportedDatepicker.manualDateChange(null, true);
                      clearDate(element)
                    "
                  >
                    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </button>
                </div>

ts code-
private dateString(startDate: NgbDate) {
    return new Date(startDate.year, startDate.month - 1, startDate.day + 1).toISOString();
  }
  onMinDateReported(ngbDate: NgbDate, element: any) {
    element['defaultValue'] = this.dateString(ngbDate).slice(0, 10);
  }

The value in element[devaultvalue] is going as 17/07/2024 but in UI it is showing as 16/06/2024.
When I select a date, it should correctly display the selected date, instead of a day before.
